# Curved Arrows showing trade ARCGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography, point, flow-map

I have 10 points that represent the centres of countries. I want to show with arrows the flow (some kind of trade) from one country to another.

The way that my table of attributes is constructed is the following:

From country      X Y       To country    X_to  Y_to            Value 
1                 X Y       2             X_to  Y_to            10

I want the arrows to be proportional to the value and not to be straight lines but curved as it may be the case that 2 countries exchange trade, i.e. country 1 sends to country 2 and country 2 sends to country 1.

ARCGIS 10.2

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us which GIS software do you use.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92376/how-do-i-create-a-flow-line-map-for-my-data

Comment: Here is a solution from the duplicate post: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2012/09/12/generating-distributive-flow-maps-with-arcgis/

Answer (score 3):

If you know how to use javascript and [d3](http://d3js.org/), then the [spatialsankey](https://github.com/geodesign/spatialsankey) d3 plugin might help. [Here is an example](http://bl.ocks.org/03cd4a6c72f661377f7e) application that does something similar to what you ask, though only to show flows in one direction.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot!

Comment: Is it working? I downloaded the data here: https://gist.github.com/yellowcap/03cd4a6c72f661377f7e
but I just got the map, the data doesn't seem to load

Comment: Oh, it is working. The problem was "cross origin" one using Chrome. It works in Firefox or from a server. Great work by the way yellowcap, thank you!

Comment: Thanks Albert! Glad it worked. Do you know how I could update it so that it works in chrome as well? The online "bl.ocks.org" version does works on chrome I think.

Answer (score 2):

A search with Google threw up these pages...

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/09/06/creating-radial-flow-maps-with-arcgis/

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2012/09/12/generating-distributive-flow-maps-with-arcgis/

Someone has even created a tool that flows around country boundaries.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=04fa6ed8746b451892f339011aaf989d